# need to reload variable after updating attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

WHen I'm testing in rspec or cucumber, everytime I update an attribute, I have to "reload" the variable again:

```
  @answer.update_attributes(notified: false)
  @answer = Answer.find(@answer)
```

Otherwise @answer doesn't update. This seems inefficient. Is this right? Am I doing something wrong or this is the way it's suposed to work?

Edit: complete spec

```
describe "notify method" do

  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    friend = generate_friend_for_user(@user)
    @answer = FactoryGirl.create(:answer, user: friend, contact: @user.service)
    @answer.update_attributes(notified: false)
    @answer = Answer.find(@answer)
  end

it "should send an email and update last_email field" do
  @user.update_attributes(last_email: 25.hours.ago)
  @answer.notify.should == true
  @user = User.find(@user)
  @user.last_email.should > 1.minute.ago
end
```

Comment: Can you post one of your specs? that's not the expected behavior. For that little code you could do: '@answer.notified = false' or '@answer.assign_attributes(notified: false, key: value, key: value, etc...)', but '@answer.update_attributes' should work just fine... also, you have an @answer.reload method (but you shouldn't need it there)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the issue, and I can see that using `ActiveRecord#update` reloads the record in memory, while `ActiveRecord#update_attributes` does not. Is there a specific reason why you are using `ActiveRecord#update_attributes`? The method is also deprecated in Rails 6.